# Type Math Equation in Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, mathml

Is there any solution in ASP.NET/C# or Jquery for writing math equations as MathML is not very well supported by browsers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of services that will translate LaTeX equations into an image for you.

For example, here's a relatively famous equation using `codecogs.com`.

[image: e=mc^2]

In this case, the url is: `https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?e%3Dmc%5E2` (`e=mc^2` post url-encoding).

That specific website also has a little [equation editor](http://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php) to give you a hand in writing your LaTeX equation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several attempts at generating equations in HTML. [This is one](http://people.hofstra.edu/Stefan_Waner/equation/codeindex.html). There are several others but I haven't used any in projects myself so I cannot say how good these are.